# Fix broken transactional replication in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication, transactional-replication

I've set-up a transactional replication in SQL Server 2005 and I've disabled the DDL trigger that were created when setting up replication. After playing a bit (to understand what will happen) the transaction is broken, because I've changed a column on publisher to `VARCHAR` that is `INT` on subscriber. I've found two procedure, which will help to skip this buggy transaction

```
EXEC sp_helpsubscriptionerrors
    @publisher='DB1',@publisher_db='repl_test',@publication='repl_test_table',
    @subscriber='DB2',@subscriber_db='repl_test'
```

That gives me a resultset where I can see the error (failure on converting `VARCHAR` to `INT`)

```
id time                    [...] error_code error_text                                             xact_seqno
24 2012-02-23 08:33:35.313 [...] 8114       Fehler beim Konvertieren des varchar-Datentyps in int. 0x00139791000CC79C000600000000
24 2012-02-23 08:33:35.310 [...] 8114       Fehler beim Konvertieren des varchar-Datentyps in int. 0x00139791000CC79C000600000000
[...]
```

and I use the `xact_seqno` from result (0x00139791000CC79C000600000000) to execute following procedure in next step

```
EXEC sp_setsubscriptionxactseqno
    @publisher='DB1',@publisher_db='repl_test',@publication='repl_test_table',
    @xact_seqno=0x00139791000CC79C000600000000
```

which will say:

> Error 20017 - The subscription doesn't exist on subscriber.

Huh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahhhh, having a look at [internal code](http://www.g-productions.nl/index.php?name=sp_setsubscriptionxactseqno) of `sp_setsubscriptionxactseqno` one can see, that this procedure has to be executed *in* the subscription database (and not in `distribution` database, where `sp_helpsubscriptionerrors` has to be executed)...but this isn't documented in MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Did executing sp_setsubscriptionxactseqno on the subscriber work for you?

You can also use the Distribution Agent parameter **-SkipErrors 8114** to temporarily skip this error type.

[Skipping Errors in Transactional Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151331.aspx)